# Connect external Ethernet AP

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, ethernet, dhcp

I want to use an external WiFi Access Point connected to my RPi through the Ethernet (not USB). The DHCP server must be on RPi and wireless clients have to connect to a service running on RPi.
I'm using Raspbian and i tried configuring the DHCP server on Raspberry but i cannot configure it to route network traffic to correct IP addresses.

The structure is like this:

**RPi** <---- *RJ45* ----->  **AP**  ---))) *WiFi* ---)))  clients

How i have to configure dhcpd (or dnsmasq) to route correctly to reach external clients?

Thank you.